# jsf and twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I have a datatable and I would like the user to click on a row and reveal more info about that row in a twitter modal. The datatable works fine but the modal will not pop up when i click. I followed instructions to call the pop up function manually but it does not work.

The data table and modal definitions:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <h:form id="modalForm">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Use backing Bean property here... <h:outputText value="#{ajaxBean.car.name}"/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </h:form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function openModal(modalName) {
    $(myModal).modal('show');
    return false;
  }
</script>

<h:form>
  <h:dataTable id="dataTable" var="c" value="#{employeebean.cars}" styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
      #{c.name}
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
      <h:commandLink  onclick="$(#myModal).modal('hide');" value="Edit">
        <!-- the listener sets the variable in backing bean and onevent opens the modal -->
        <!-- you also have to render the form inside the modal, so the values get updated with new ones from backing bean -->
        <f:ajax listener="#{ajaxBean.handleEvent}" onevent="openModal('myModal');" render=":modalForm" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

A Bean:

```
public class Employeebean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private List<Car> cars;
  private Car selectedCar;

  public Car getSelectedCar() {
    return selectedCar;
  }

  public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
     this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars.add(new Car(1,"King","Asomaning","king.png","halo-5.png",10.0,
  }

  public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
  }

  public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
  }
}
```

Another Bean:

```
public class AjaxBean {
  private Car car;

  public final void handleEvent(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    //get the member from the FacesContext.
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.car = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{c}", Car.class);
  }

  public Car getCar() {
    return car;
  }

  public void setMember(Car car) {
    this.car = car;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After many differents ways and solutions over the internet I got this:

The code of the h:commandLing nested into a  html attribute

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" 
jsfc="h:commandLink"
type="button"
action="#{pesquisaSubgrupoBean.setSubgrupoSelecionado(subgrupo)}"
immediate="true">
                   <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                    value="#{subgrupo}" 
                    target="#{pesquisaSubgrupoBean.subgrupoSelecionado}"/>

                   <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-toggle" value="modal" />
                   <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-target" value="#myModal" />
                   <f:param
                    name="descricaoSubgrupo"
                    value="#{subgrupo.descricao}"></f:param>
                   <f:ajax
                    execute="@this"/>

<i class="icon_close_alt2"></i>
```

And the code of the modal form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmação de exclusão</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <h:panelGroup 
                layout="block" 
                id="panelDescricao">

                Deseja realmente excluir o registro selecionado?

                <a  type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                    jsfc="h:commandLink"
                    action="#{pesquisaSubgrupoBean.excluir()}">
                    Sim
                        <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-dismiss" value="modal" />
                    <f:ajax
                        execute="@this"
                        render="@form"/>
                </a>

                <button 
                    id="close"
                    type="submit" 
                    class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Não</button>
            </h:panelGroup>
            </div>

        </h:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just could not do the value updated on `<f:setPropertyActionListenter>` be shown on the modal form. The method is called after the render of the modal. I will work on this.